# QuickBlox add server logic

Tags: quickblox

Is it possible to add server logic in QuickBlox? For example, I want to send a message to all existing chat rooms in my app every 20 - 30 seconds. The only way I see now is to place my program on another server, that will register as another user and connect to all existing rooms, sending messages. Is there any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to upload custom code to QuickBlox server now,

As a workaround - write simple script (in python, ruby) which will do that, upload it to some server (or home PC), run it on CRON. Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you mean that I have to do the whole procedure of authentication (with app credentials) and registering, using REST API? Is it possible to write such thing on Java(since I'm planning to use few other Java libs)?

Comment: Yes, you need to login to Chat, retrieve list of rooms, send message to each room. And schedule this code to run each 30 seconds.

Comment: Here is list of XMPP libs http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/
Smack is the most popular for Java applications

Comment: @IgorKhomenko is QuickBlox running XMPP for the chat implementation? Can the chat server for my QuickBlox app be accessed directly via Smack?

Comment: @emkman yes, it's XMPP and you can use Smack without any problems